# Cannot open backup device - SQL Server on-premise backup database to Azure storage

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-storage, database-administration

I have a database running on an on-premise SQL Server instance. I've set up a SQL agent to backup the database every night and store in a container in Azure. However, I'm seeing the following error after the job runs:

```
Message
Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. Cannot open backup device 'https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mystoragecontainer/20200102/MYDATABASE_0.bak'. Operating system error 50(The request is not supported.). [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3201)  BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3013)
```

The Azure storage account is Storage (general purpose v1).

SQL Server 13.0.5233.0
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      14.0.17213.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        14.0.1016.232
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     10.0.14393.0
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.14393.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                        6.3.14393

Is there a way of configuring NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT to connect to the Azure storage container?

Comment: Have you tried with a credential? These instructions seem pretty thorough: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-sql-server-backup-and-restore-to-azure-blob-storage-service

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've followed the steps. When I attempt to sign in to Azure, after entering my login details, I see the following message: ```TITLE: Create Credential
------------------------------

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Azure.UI)
```

Comment: Please try to update SSMS to the latest  version  18.4 or 17.9 and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the comments are valid to a certain extent. I finally fixed (term used loosely) backing up my SQL Server database to an Azure storage container using SAS (shared access signature) credentials.

1. Deleted the existing credential in SQL Server (under Security > Credentials)
2. In Azure, created an access policy under Storage Account > Container. It's important to define start and expiration dates/times, and time zones along with read, write level.
3. In Azure, Generate a SAS token for the container. Ensure you set the appropriate start and expiration dates/times along with the timezone. Don't rely on just UTC.
4. Upload a file to the container to make sure it's all ok.
5. In SQL Server, create the credentials. The secret should be the SAS token without the preceding ?, so just "sv=...." .

```
IF NOT EXISTS  
(SELECT * FROM sys.credentials   
WHERE name = 'https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer')  
CREATE CREDENTIAL [https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer] 
   WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',  
   SECRET = 'sv=_my_sas_key_without_?';
```

6. Backup the database. The URL and container must match with the credentials - in this case, https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer .

```
BACKUP DATABASE [mydatabase]   
TO URL = 'https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/mydatabase_03012020120400.bak' 
WITH FORMAT,  
COMPRESSION,
STATS=5,
BLOCKSIZE=65536,
MAXTRANSFERSIZE=4194304;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like access related issue.To be able to back up to Azure Blob Storage, your backup command must have a valid credential that has access to the blob storage. This can be done in two ways:

Review your credentials, make sure your access key is correct and, if you’re using SAS, make sure that the access policy is defined and you are pointing to the correct container that it has access to.  For more information on URL backups as well as script samples, please refer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url?view=sql-server-2017

- Shared Access Signature
- Identity and Access Key

Additional reference:

https://blog.pythian.com/how-to-fix-sql-backup-to-url-failure-operating-system-error-50/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm finding that backing up to Azure storage works using storage account identity and access key, but see the error when using Shared Access Signature.